# In transitive (non-trivial) group action, there must be at least one group element without fixed point

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof, group-actions

Let a finite group $G$ act transitively on a finite set $S$ with $|S| \geq 2$.
The problem is to show that not every $g \in G$ can have a fixed point in this action. I proved this on my own, but I'm looking for alternate proofs.

My proof:

> $G$ acts transitively so we can write $S = G.s$.
>
>
>  Assume that every $g \in G$ has a fixed point $h_g.s$. Then 
>  $g \in \operatorname{Stab}(h_g.s) = h_g \operatorname{Stab}(s) h_g^{-1}$.
>  It turns out that $G$ is equal to the union of conjugates of 
>  $\operatorname{Stab}(s)$, but [that can't happen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121526/union-of-the-conjugates-of-a-proper-subgroup) unless $|S| = 1$.

Comment: We know that if the action is transitive, then the number of orbits is $1$, thus $1= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \pi(g)$ where $\pi$ is the corresponding permutation character. Then there must be some $g\in G$ with $\pi(g)=0$, so there exists an element which fix nothing.

Comment: Some other proofs here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820572/g-acts-on-x-transitively-then-there-exists-some-element-that-does-not-have-any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t$ denote the number of orbits of $G$ acting on $S$. By the Cauchy-Frobenius Lemma (the lemma that is not Burnside's), $t = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} |fix(g)|$, where $|fix(g)|$ is the number of points in $S$ that are fixed by $g$.  In other words, the number of orbits is equal to the average value of the number of fixed points of permutations in $G$.

When the group action is transitive, $t=1$. The identity permutation $1_G$ fixes more than 1 point (assuming $|S| \ge 2$).  Because the identity permutation contributes a value larger than 1, in order for the average value to be equal to 1, some permutation must contribute a value less than 1, ie, some permutation in $G$ has 0 fixed points.