# Transitive group action and fixed point

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have the following problem: 
Let $G$ be a finite group with transitive group action on a set $X$ (#$X > 1$). Prove: there exists an element $g \in G$ such that $gx \neq x$ for all $x \in X$.

It would be nice if anyone could help me getting started. Usually with these problems, I have trouble understanding what information I have given. 
I know that transitive action is: $Gx = X$ for some $x \in X$. But how can I use this definition?

Regards.

Comment: If it's not the case then $\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in X}Stab(x) = G$. You can use the orbit-stabiliser theorem to compute the order of $Stab(x)$ and find a contradiction

Comment: This question was already asked, you can find the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820572/g-acts-on-x-transitively-then-there-exists-some-element-that-does-not-have-any

Comment: A hint to get started is "Burnsides lemma". If you want a full solution, click on the above link.